# Help with sentence construction

Tags: grammar

我本来只是抱着试一试的想法去参加比赛的， 没想到居然获得了冠军。 这不但让朋友感到吃惊而且让父母很高兴。

I found this sentence difficult to understand mostly because of 我本来只是抱着试一试的想法去参加比赛的 and don't know how to break it down.

我本来 I originally
只是 only?
抱着试一试的想法 hug and try at the same time? thoughts?
参加比赛的 attend the game

Obviously, I am in a mess and need some clearing up.

Thank you.

Comment: **bkrs** ：抱 (8) 怀藏, 心里存有 [cherish] **iciba** ：不抱幻想了was soon disillusioned，抱同情 sympathetic  抱憾 regret;be sorry 心存遗憾， 抱恨  have a gnawing regret 心中怀有恨事， 抱恨终天 harbor an eternal sorrow 终天:终其天年,即终生。指心存怨恨难消,直到死

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpretation of 我本來 and 衹是 are fine.

- 抱着 (literally *to hug*, but should be interpreted as *to grasp onto*)
- 試一試的想法 (a thought of just trying)
- 參加比賽的 (to participate in a competition)

> 我本來衹是抱着試一試的想法去參加比賽的
>
> *I originally participated in the competition holding on to the thought of just giving it a go*

Comment: Is there also a 是。。 的 construction here? Or is 只是 a word itself?

Comment: @金允雄Oliver 只是 in your sentence means *only*.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments the only thing you're missing is:

> 抱着....的想法

To hold a [certain] idea.